# How can I extract images from an MPTS video(which has 4 videos in it) from each and every video using a single command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an MPTS video file, which has 4 videos in it. I want to extract images from each video and store them in a directory separately. I am using ffmpeg, I have seen references from previous solved questions.

I used below command to extract frames.

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -i input.ts -s 400x222 -qscale:v 4 -start_number 0 -vf fps=1 /storage/frames/input_1//%d.jpg /storage/frames/input_2//%d.jpg /storage/frames/input_3//%d.jpg /storage/frames/input_4//%d.jpg
```

But frames extracted only for first video in MPTS stream. How can I achieve using this using a single ffmpeg command?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map all 4 streams in separate outputs.

```
ffmpeg -threads:v 8 -i input.ts \
       -map 0:v:0 -vf fps=1 -s 400x222 -qscale:v 4 -start_number 0 /storage/frames/input_1//%d.jpg \
       -map 0:v:1 -vf fps=1 -s 400x222 -qscale:v 4 -start_number 0 /storage/frames/input_2//%d.jpg \
       -map 0:v:2 -vf fps=1 -s 400x222 -qscale:v 4 -start_number 0 /storage/frames/input_3//%d.jpg \
       -map 0:v:3 -vf fps=1 -s 400x222 -qscale:v 4 -start_number 0 /storage/frames/input_4//%d.jpg
```